# Running a search query in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am on MVC3 & Entity Framework.

Is there a direct way to run user's search query on a text column in Entity Framework (linq?) ?

Like, if the user types - **(john or orders) and washington**, the sql query automatically interprets the expression and returns the results.

If not, what are the other options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No. Option is to parse your query language and either construct valid Linq query or ESQL.